# jfx webview with Basic auth does not notice that it is logged in at the first attempt

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine, xwiki

First of all, beginner here.
Goal:
I would like to access a page of my wiki(xWiki) with basic authentication and **Openjdk 8**.
Problem:
It doesn't recognize on the first attempt that im already logged in visually. So it doesn't load for example Buttons that are only available logged in
If i refresh the page, it works. 
If i switch to another page, it works.
It just doesn't work the first time you open the page.
What i've tryed:
I changed openjdk and openjfx version to 11 and it worked.
Access the Site with firefox browser works.
Adding Webengine state listener but without success(The idea was to wait until it was fully loaded).
Work around:
Call the method twice or reload webengine but that doesn't feel right.
Note:
Using Apache 2.4 and Tomcat 8.5
Using Wireshark shows that bootstrap is not loaded?(not really sure)
Plaintext credentials and http just for test purposes.
Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 1500, 1000, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        String login = "foo";
        String password = "foo";
        String loginPassword = login + ":" + password;
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(loginPassword.getBytes());
        webEngine.setUserAgent(webEngine.getUserAgent().concat("\nAuthorization: Basic " + encoded));
        webEngine.load("http://localhost/foo");
        getChildren().add(browser);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser, 0, 0, w, h, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: You tested it with a more recent version of JavaFX and it worked.  So use a recent version of JavaFX than the obsolete JavaFX 8 version.

Comment: @jewelsea
The next goal is to implement a webview in an application. This application cannot currently be upgraded to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Authentication/#HBasicAuthentication

> https://username:password@mywiki.xwiki.com/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome?basicauth=1

Try adding the `basicauth=1` query string parameter that signals XWiki to accept your submitted basic authentication header and log you in.

Comment: i added ?basicauth=1, doesn´t work unfortunately